# get data from tags in summary section in Azure DevOps site to be used in Power BI

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

I want to get data from tags field in Summary section in Azure Dev Ops using Power BI odata feed connector. is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Shin, Is the explanation in my answer helpful to you? Please have a check with it. Any question about this, feel free to tell us.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT yes. thanks for your confirmation. i just wonder if there is any other way to extract information on this section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, we have no method to get data from the project Summary page to Power BI.

With Power BI, you can pull data from Azure DevOps Analytics. And currently, the data available from Analytics are from **Boards**, **Pipelines** and **Test Plans**.

To view more details, you can see:

- [**About Power BI integration**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/overview?view=azure-devops)
- [**What is the Analytics service?**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/what-is-analytics?view=azure-devops)
- [**Data available from Analytics**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-available-in-analytics?view=azure-devops)

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I did read the documentation before asking here. Just want to confirm it. Thanks for your confirmation.